# How to organise a homestay in Myanmar?

Tags: local-customs, southeast-asia, local-cuisine, myanmar, homestay

My wife and I are planning a trip to Southeast Asia over a long period (~5 months).  One of my goals of this trip is to try and engage with locals, to learn about their language, culture and just generally socialise in a comfortable environment.  I know that this won't be the case in many situations; as English-speaking Westerners I know we stand out significantly and I'm not looking to downplay any differences.  But where possible, I would like to understand what life is like from most locals' perspective, for instance being able to visit a home and share a meal with a family.

My question is, how would I go about organising something like a homestay or a meal with a local family in Myanmar?  I'm doing as much research as possible, but given its history as a relatively closed-off nation until a few years ago, there isn't much advice on how best to organise something like a homestay or share a meal with a local family.

Any advice would be appreciated.

(FYI - I have travelled to India and Indonesia before, so I have *some* idea of the cultural differences that exist.  But I'm certainly open to any feedback, tips, advice.)

Comment: This is going to be extremely difficult regarding the requirements that you stay in a government registered accommodation.

Comment: Not been to Myanmar so can't post an answer. Generally if you do tourist research, you will find a set-up for tourists. My approach to discover a country, is to travel around using the typical means of transport that the inhabitants use. That allows me to engage with them, and from time to time, I get an invitation to visit their home. But even then, it won't be their "normal" meal - it will be a special meal for guests, and might even stretch their resources.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas is that still a requirement?  I thought perhaps those restrictions had been relaxed in the past few years.

Comment: @ptikobj It was as of two years ago when I was there last, and I've not heard otherwise. But I welcome hearing from someone who has visited since to contradict me. :)

Answer (score 3):

It isn't possible. I go to Myanmar every two months, and the visa application mentions this clearly. You need to stay in government-approved lodgings, and staying with locals is forbidden.

While Myanmar is a great place to visit, it is still a dictatorship, and the government still holds a tight grip on the country.